# How can I set default value of a Combo in a datagrid but with lot of rows changing the value? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Rows is ok, but I need to see the results over the combo, I've tried with selected index, it didn't work.

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn   Header="Cheque/Transf." Width="105" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyle}" >
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <ComboBox                                                                  
                                                              FontSize="10"
                                                              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                                              Path=DataContext.ChequeTransf}"   
                                                              DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion"
                                                              SelectedValuePath="Descripcion" 
                                                              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=cTipoTransaccion,Mode=TwoWay,
                                                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                               
                                                              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=cbxIdTransaccion,Mode=TwoWay,
                                                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                        
                                                     ></ComboBox>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: The code you have posted isn't the proper syntax for wpf.  Could you post your actual DataGrid?

Comment: I've edited Felix

Comment: It's the variable which will save when I select the row selected

Comment: `SelectedValue` binding is right way to achieve what you want, just need to understand why it not binds or not sets. Does `cTipoTransaccion` has initial value? Or does it sets on Window Loaded?

Comment: I set cTipoTransaccion when I select the row of my datagrid

Comment: I just wanna set a value in the selectedindex